# How to get which view in the hierarchy was touched?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uiview-hierarchy

I have an UIview V of type MyUView, which contains a stackView named S1. The S stack contains a stackview named NM, which contains a UITextField named T and another stackview named M, whose contains an UILabel named L. For the sake of simplicity i've used letters for namid the controls.

the hierarchy of views is as follows:

- V

  - S1

    - NM

      - T
      - M

        - L

I have added a LongPressGestureRecognizer named lprecognizer to the view V in order to recognize longpress gestures. I want is to detect longPress gestures (and possible other gestures too) on the view but, if the gesture is a longpress gesture i want to do a specific action only if the uitextfield T was the touched view.

I implemented in MyUView the following delegate method:

```
- (Bool) gestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer*) gesturerecognizer shouldreceiveTouch: (UITouch*) touch {

  if (gestureRecognizer == lprecognizer)
  {
    if (touch.view == T) return YES;
    else return NO;
  }
  else return YES;
}
```

this is not working (even if I touch the textfield) because the view that the gesture recognized as the touched one is the Stack S1, which is the first and only view in the subview array of view V (remember the hierarchy mentioned before).

My question is:

**If there any SIMPLE way to know if a certain view of interest (say for instance a UITextField) is in the area of a gicen touch even when this view of interest is way deep in the hierarchy of views??**

I would like to avoid the idea of searching recursively thought the hierarchy of views.

Comment: "I would like to avoid the idea of searching recursively thought the hierarchy of views" Why? That's what the system is doing!

Comment: Does `hitTest` on `UIView` help?

Comment: the hitText method helps to go one level deep in the hierarchy but it does not go all the way to the deepest node containing the touched point...I was hoping there was a method or a simple way of doing that but it seems I must call recursively the hitTest method...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
UIView *hitView = [touch.view hitTest:[touch locationInView:touch.view] withEvent:nil];

if (hitView == T) {
    // etc
}
```

Comment: This is not working either...the touched view is now the stackView NM...I think that I probably ending up calling recursively the hitTest method until the obtained view has no subviews (which is the case of the UITextField T)...does anybody knows another way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

there is anther way to identify by using  Touch point like this

```
 let position = touch.locationInView(self)

 if CGRectContainsPoint(T.frame, position) {
      // you have touch on textField T
  }
```

Comment: Well, I finally end up searching recursively through the hierarchy of views because Hittest does not go all the way down in the hierarchy. Besides, I've also noticed that there were sometimes in which, even when visually the touch point was inside a view, that same view does not recognize the touch was inside it when the HitTest method is called on it and using the touch location; so, I decided to use the CGRectContainsPoint method you suggest me in the recursive search. Thus, although it was not all the answer it certainty helps me to find it. I’ll give you points for that, Thank you!!.